# Why doesn't scale_edge_width_identity(guide = "legend") work?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggraph

I am using ggraph to plot two networks containing nodes and edges of varying sizes and widths, respectively.

I want to maintain the absolute sizes of nodes and edges using `scale_size_identity()` and `scale_edge_width_identity()`.

I'd like to display legends and am using `scale_size_identity(legend = "guide")` for nodes, which works as expected, but for edges `scale_edge_width_identity(legend = "guide")` I get the following error:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

If I don't provide `legend = "guide"` to `scale_edge_width_identity()`, everything works. The variable I'm scaling is numeric. This problem also occurs if I'm using `scale_edge_alpha_identity(legend = "guide")` Why is this and is there any way I can still show the legends? Appreciate any suggestions.

UPDATE:
It works with the suggestion by @teunbrand below. However, I noticed that `scale_size_continuous()` for scaling node size does not work with this approach. Use `scale_radius()` instead:

```r
# building on example by @teunbrand
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
require(tidygraph)
#> Loading required package: tidygraph
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(patchwork)

gr <- create_notable("bull")
layout <- create_layout(gr, layout = "igraph", algorithm = "kk")

edge_guide <- guide_legend()

# Edges are plotted using the same scale but nodes are not when scale_size_continuous() is used.
# Notice the differently sized nodes between the legend guides:
ggraph(layout) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = seq(1, 5, length.out = 5))) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_width = seq(1, 5, length.out = 5))) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 5), breaks = c(1, 3, 5)) +
  scale_edge_width_continuous(range = c(1, 5), breaks = c(1, 2, 3)) |
ggraph(layout) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = seq(1, 10, length.out = 5))) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_width = seq(1, 10, length.out = 5))) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1, 10), breaks = c(1, 3, 5)) +
  scale_edge_width_continuous(range = c(1, 10), breaks = c(1, 2, 3))
```

[plotOutput1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nI2k.png)

```r
# However, using scale_radius() instead does the job:
ggraph(layout) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = seq(1, 5, length.out = 5))) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_width = seq(1, 5, length.out = 5))) +
  scale_radius(range = c(1, 5), breaks = c(1, 3, 5)) +
  scale_edge_width_continuous(range = c(1, 5), breaks = c(1, 2, 3)) |
ggraph(layout) +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = seq(1, 10, length.out = 5))) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_width = seq(1, 10, length.out = 5))) +
  scale_radius(range = c(1, 10), breaks = c(1, 3, 5)) +
  scale_edge_width_continuous(range = c(1, 10), breaks = c(1, 2, 3)) 


Created on 2020-12-04 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

[plotOutput2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8myW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the confusion and this might be a bug, but here are workarounds. The workaround is basically to use the `_continuous()` version of the scales to mimick the `_identity()` version as close as possible by setting the range to the exact range of the data.

```r
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
require(tidygraph)
#> Loading required package: tidygraph
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter

gr <- create_notable('bull')
layout <- create_layout(gr, layout = 'igraph', algorithm = 'kk')

edge_guide <- guide_legend()

ggraph(layout) +
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_width = 1:5)) +
  scale_edge_width_continuous(range = c(1, 5))
```

[image]

```r
ggraph(layout) +
  geom_node_point() +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_alpha = seq(0.1, 1, length.out = 5))) +
  scale_edge_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.1, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>